# where should phpmyadmin folder be saved?

Tags: phpmyadmin

apache, mysql and phpmyadmin tutorial and the tutorial suggests to navigate to localhost/phpmyadmin/setup, however this gives me "the site cannot be reached" in the browser.

I have already ran "sudo apachectl start"

I think this is likely that I have phpmyadmin saved in the wrong folder but the tutorial doesn't explain which folder to save it in, so I currently have it in a downloads folder.

Can anyone tell me where to move phpmyadmin folder and how to get it to work

edit: I am using mac os x

Answer (score 0):

FIrst, you have to find your web root folder. This is the folder where files are being served. Typically on a Linux system, it will be `/var/www/` but it depends on the Linux distribution you're using and the specific configuration you have. Once you have figured out the root directory of your website, simply add a directory called `phpmyadmin`. So in the typical case, you now have `/var/www/phpmyadmin`

To find the web directory, it is referred to as `DocumentRoot` in apache's configuration file.